# Search criteria matching for oracle update/insert

Tags: oracle, notifications, in-memory, complex-event-processing

I have a Oracle table which is updated by a server #1.
Also, there is another server #2 that has a set of search criteria.

**Example :**

```
column1=100 and column2 > 5 and column3 < 5000 and column4 == 'hello'
```

The server #2 can have hundreds of such criteria.
When ever the server #1 **inserts/updates** a row in the oracle db table, I need to somehow check whether that row is matching any of the criteria.
How do I achieve something like this?

Example table1:

```html
<html>
    <table border="1">
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>salary</th><th>taxslab</th></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC</td><td>30</td><td>10000</td><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DEF</td><td>40</td><td>20000</td><td>20</td></tr>
    </table>
    </html>
```

Search criteria #1 is `taxslab >= 30`

Whenever I insert another row `(XYZ, 20, 50000, 40)` in the table, a notification needs to be sent out as the new row is matching the stored search criteria.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: looks like a trigger is sufficient for this purpose. show us sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dynamic SQL (`execute immediate using out...`) for each condition separately. Assuming you know what you insert, you can execute something like:

```
select 1
  from table 
 where <my_condtion_1>
   and my_primary_key=my_inserted_data 
   and rownum = 1
```

If output is 1, then the new/updated data matches condition 1. Do that for all rows/conditions for the table.

Pack everything in a trigger, as âńōŋŷXmoůŜ mentioned.